# Should we have a Citation Helper?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It looks like a great deal of questions so far are about theoretical aspects of proof assistants and the underlying type theories. The answers to these questions rely on academic papers and conference proceedings. A citation helper tool might be helpful quickly inserting appropriate citations and online links when available.

MathOverflow has had such a tool for a while: [New feature - citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2583/new-feature-citation-helper). This tool is specifically designed for Mathematics (e.g. the primary databases it is designed for are [zbMath](https://zbmath.org/) and [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search.html)). This tool could presumably be ported to fit the needs of this community.

Comment: Are you volunteering to do this if the community wants it? :)

Comment: This was proposed 12 years ago on MSE, there's an [answer that supports multiple standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375748/282094), with a link to open source code.

Comment: @JasonRute It's already done! All we would need is a selection of sources and, if necessary, authorization to use such sources. And then properly formatting results from such databases.